System.IO.IOException occurs when running any project in Visual Studio 2022
use the latest version of Visual Studio(Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.11.0)
Every project I run, this exception occurs. As you can see in the image below, I ran a simple api project and an error occurs.


Event Type Moniker    Event   Time    Duration    Thread  Exception thrown:
'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll ("Received an
unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Exception
thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll ("Received
an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Hyperlink:
Activate Historical Debugging 1.86s       [28724] Worker Thread

and

Event Type Moniker    Event   Time    Duration    Thread  Exception thrown:
'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll ("Received an
unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Exception
thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
("Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.")
Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging  1.86s       [28724] Worker Thread

and

Event Type Moniker    Event   Time    Duration    Thread  Exception thrown:
'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll ("Received an
unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Exception
thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll ("Received
an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Hyperlink:
Activate Historical Debugging 1.86s       [28736] Worker Thread

and

Event Type Moniker    Event   Time    Duration    Thread  Exception thrown:
'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll ("Received an
unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Exception
thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
("Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.")
Hyperlink: Activate Historical Debugging  1.86s       [28732] Worker Thread

and

Event Type Moniker    Event   Time    Duration    Thread  Exception thrown:
'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll ("Received an
unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Exception
thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Net.Security.dll ("Received
an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.") Hyperlink:
Activate Historical Debugging 1.86s       [28732] Worker Thread

Even the new project that I create and run, I face these exceptions.
I don't know where the problem is and how to fix it.

What .NET version are you using? Did you try upping the version? Check out this github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44650

@MilosStojanovic I use the latest version net8.0

As @adityamandaleeka asked in provided link, can you pass build process and does your app run normally even with errors? Did you try with some other .NET version or VS version? Did you try reinstalling VS or .NET? Does it happen in Debug and all other modes also?

The project runs without problems. But in one of my projects, I use rabbitmq and masstransit, so the exceptions are repeated a lot. I tested with .NET 6 and it has the same problem.

The only thing that comes to mind is clean install of .NET and VS. Since I can't find any other mention of this problem except provided github issues, I'm not sure what would be the next step.
